# django celery rabbitmq execute delay

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I use Django-Celery +rabbitmq to execute some asyn tasks,I define a queue 'sendmail' to execute send email task,send mail is triggered by a specific task(this task has own queue), but now I encounter a problem,after the specific task finish, the mail sometimes send at once, sometimes need 5-20minutes.I want to know what reason caused it.

Django-celery will package the taskname and param as message to rabbitmq when call task.delay().

I want to know when the message go to the rabbitmq, but use web management tool only can see total messages,can't see the every message's detail, especially the time the message reached. Django-celery log can only see the work got from broker time and execute task time.I want to know all related timepoint to sure which step the time main consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Django-Celery does (I believe) report task data on a per-task basis.  When you sync your database, it crates a bunch of monitoring tables which are accessible via the admin.  However, in order for these tasks to be recorded in these tables, you need to run the celerycam program in the django context (python ./manage.py celerycam).  The celerycam program will take "snapshots" of your tasks every second or so (by default) and record information about them. Another useful tool for monitoring is the celerymon program (which also has to run in the django context).  This is a command line ncurses program that reports real-time information about tasks as they occur.  Finally, rabbitmqctrl has a bunch of options that might help with monitoring.

This is a particularly useful page in the docs: 
http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/monitoring.html

Anyway, this is what I use to monitor my tasks when using celery.